# The difference between the two initialization?

Tags: c++, class, oop, function-call

What are the differential factors between these two transformation initialization constructs?

```
int main()
{
     VectorXYZ NewLocation = VectorXYZ(30, 30, 0);
     SetLocation(NewLocation);

// and

     SetLocation(VectorXYZ(30, 30, 0));
}
```

Comment: The second one operates on a temporary.

Comment: is it practical?

Comment: Yes. You may find it useful not needing to create a variable and assign it a name to initialize a location.

Comment: If there are no side effects, the whole program may be optimized away.

Comment: From a practical standpoint, use the style that is most readable.  Unless profiling of optimized code shows that there is a significant penalty for using that style over something more contorted, trust the optimizer to be able to do some amazing things.  (What is "most readable" is opinion based, and will vary by team or individuals.)

Comment: How is SetLocation defined?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I didn't understand a bit about optimization

Comment: The latter can participate in move-semantics if possible; the former constructs a concrete object which *may* be passed by reference (but we don't know since you didn't bother to include any useful information about `SetLocation`, nor do we know about any potential overloads of said-same). Even if passed by non-const ref and gutted by an unseen move in `SetLocation`, you're still left with the shell-of-self back here in `main`. As far as initialization, however, there is only one direct-initialization to concrete object in this code, so I'm not clear what you think you're really asking.

Comment: @MaskOryle What I meant was that If the compiler is able to realize that your program doesn't actually do anything, it may optimize the whole thing to a program similar to `int main(){}`

Answer (score 3):

If the function SetLocation is declared for example like

```
void SetLocation( VectorXYZ & );
```

then  you may it call like

```
SetLocation(NewLocation);
```

but may not call it like

```
 SetLocation(VectorXYZ(30, 30, 0));
```

because you may not bind a temporary object with a non constant lvalue reference.

On the other hand, if the function is declared like

```
void SetLocation( VectorXYZ && );
```

then you may call it like

```
 SetLocation(VectorXYZ(30, 30, 0));
```

but you may not call it like

```
SetLocation(NewLocation);
```

If the function is declared like

```
void SetLocation( const VectorXYZ & );
```

or like

```
void SetLocation( VectorXYZ );
```

then the both calls are valid.

Comment: If the function is declared like `void SetLocation( const VectorXYZ &)` or `void SetLocation( VectorXYZ )` may be more complete (pass by const reference or by value).

Comment: in a technical sense, it satisfies the desired result - Set location?